# jQuery - Check username from MySQL database issues

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I was wondering if someone could have a quick look at the code below and tell me if there is anything wrong.

It doesnt seem to be running the error when the username is already registered, and my JS console isnt throwing any errors either.

Code is as follows:

```
    if(iUsername.val().length > 4) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/index.php/ajax/username_availability",
            data: "username="+ iUsername,
            success: function(msg){
                if(msg == 'OK'){
                } else {
                    iUsername.siblings('.error').text('This username is already registered');
                    error = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Im getting iUsername by the following:

```
var iUsername = createProfileForm.find('#username');
```

and the PHP code to check the username is as follows ( codeigniter )

```
function username_availability()
{
    $res = $this->users->is_username_available( $this->input->post('username') );
    if($res)
        $this->output->set_output('OK');
    else
        $this->output->set_output('NOT OK');
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code that specifies `iUsername`?

Comment: What is the value of msg in the success function?

Comment: Ok, i have edited the post ... sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

```
data: "username="+ iUsername,
```

should be

```
data: "username="+ iUsername.val(),
```

You can also clean-up your if statement:

```
if(msg !== 'OK'){
    iUsername.siblings('.error').text('This username is already registered');
    error = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input .. That didnt seem to work though .. I have edited my original post

Comment: The difference is pretty basic `!==` means is not equal by both value and type. Meaning both the value 'OK' and a string. `!=` just means does not mean 'OK'